# Extracting Data from an Excel Spreadsheet and inserting to SQL database/ Data warehouse

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, ssis

I am trying to develop a web application that extracts data from a daily orders Excel sheet that is uploaded every day (manually to begin with) and then get that to upload to a server.

I have been trying to use SSIS to do this along with Visual studio 2019/2022 but keep receiving errors no matter what I try. The upload part of the system is working.. sort of, and I'm using SSIS as it was suggested by my supervisor, it appears however that there is no proper support for the feature, and as I said I keep running into ridiculous errors such as:

> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [14]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid object name 'dbo.People'.".

> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [14]]: Failed to open a fastload rowset for "[dbo].[People]". Check that the object exists in the database.

> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "OLE DB Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

> Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

The above error(s) occurred after the task was executed once, although no data was actually transferred to the database. Apparently due to a connection issue, but I have connected the database and Excel sheet correctly (or so I thought).

My question is this, is there any better way to extract data from an excel spreadsheet that is changing daily?

I would also need to then compare that data and perform some manipulation but that's a whole other kettle of fish.

I will also add that SQL, and ASP.NET (ASP.NET being the language my upload app is created in) are new to me, having started coding with SQL in September, and ASP.NET this week.

Any advice or Guidance will be greatly appreciated and I will of course answer any questions to the best of my ability.

Oh something else to add, when I'm trying to create an Integration project in Visual Studio with SDT installed, there isn't the option to create that project, I needed to download the Microsoft Server Integration Tools Project manually and separately for the integration project file to show up.

Comment: What format(file extension) is the Excel sheet?

Comment: The upload takes .xlsx (office 365), and that's what the daily sheet would be. However, when working on the SSIS package I had to change the file to .xls (2003-2007).

Comment: That doesn't sound right, @killerosity . You should be using the ACE drivers to consume xlsx files, not JET.

Comment: Do you mean where I had to change to xls? Visual Studio wouldn't allow me to connect the xlsx file, I tried to figure it out but most of what I did find was a few years old, and said that I needed the 32-bit version of SDT I think, but I had trouble enough trying to get it to work in the first place. I've had to ask on here because I'm so lost now.

Do you have any suggestions how I can do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: How big is the xlsx? In terms of number of rows?

Comment: The error above: `Invalid object name 'dbo.People`, indicates that this is a connection issue to the sql database.  I would check this connection manager first.  It seems like it is connecting to the server but can't find the table.  It might be the wrong server, database or the user lacks permissions to see the table

Comment: @Caius Jard it won't be super large, the one I'm working with now is 4 rows plus header row but it's just dummy data. The one with the real data could be anywhere from 5 to around 50, rarely higher.

Comment: @Mark Wojciechwicz, this is something I don't get because the "server" is the local desktop as that's where the database is saved, and these errors only appeared after I ran the program once and then ran it again. Genuinely am confused by this entire situation.

Comment: I asked about the size because there is a plug-in for CsvHelper that extends its abilities to reading xls and xlsx files but it struggles with tens of thousands of rows because,unlike a csv, they can't be streamed it seems.. It sounds like one option available to you is to read the file with eg c# plus csvh and the xls extensions, and then use EF to load the db. Another alternative would be to use the Ace access driver to read the file into e.g. A datatable and then push the table to sql server. Both routes would probably be around 20 lines of code..

Comment: How is the connection manager for the sql connection configured?  Are you using parameters to populate the connection string, servername or database?  Can you confirm that the table `dbo.People` still exists?

Comment: data_IsInvalid usually means that your data types do not match.